# Hide layers in a workspace from getCapabilities

Tags: geoserver

I have a Geoserver (2.10.1) with one workspace, some layers and a layer group.

Most of these layers may not make sense alone so I want to allow the users to see only the group layer and a few layers I choose (WMS/WFS services - OpenLayers, getCapabilities, getMap, ...).

I try to read [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html) and try to manage the `Users, Groups, and Roles` in Geoserver's admin page but I'm very confusing.

According to the user manual (link above):

> Providing access to layers is linked to roles. Layers and roles are
>   linked in a file called layers.properties, which is located in the
>   security directory in your GeoServer data directory

But the manual says nothing about how to manage the `Users, Groups, and Roles` in geoserver itself. I don't like to configure anything by editing files when I already have an interface to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the layer as not viewable to a user (or group) then it will not appear in a layer group either. You actually want to set the layer as not advertised which is a checkbox on the layer page. When this is unchecked the layer doesn't appear in the getcapabilities response.

[image]

Comment: Just to know: What if someone wants to use this layer and point it using code like OpenLayers?